# get max value from enum list

Tags: c#, list, enums, ienumerable

I want to get the minimum value from my enum list. I know I can:

```
return Enum.GetValues(typeof(VerloningsPeriodeType)).Cast<VerloningsPeriodeType>().Min();
```

however, this is only from the ENUM, and I want it from my var.

Something like:

```
public static ENUM_A BepaalMaxVerloningsPeriode(IEnumerable<ENUM_A> periods)
{
   return Enum.GetValues(typeof(ENUM_A)).Cast<ENUM_A>().Min();
}
```

Where do I place the `periods` var?

Comment: Missed the obvious one! Excuse me!

Comment: Replace `Enum.GetValues(typeof(ENUM_A)).Cast<ENUM_A>()` with `periods`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply call `Min` on `periods` itself:

```
public static ENUM_A BepaalMaxVerloningsPeriode(IEnumerable<ENUM_A> periods)
{
    return periods.Min();
}
```

This makes your `BepaalMaxVerloningsPeriode` method trivially simple. Your code will almost certainly be clearer if you get rid of your custom method and just call `Min` directly.